# Custom redirect using Found router w/ React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a React app and using [Found](https://github.com/4Catalyzer/found) as the router.

The [docs](https://github.com/4Catalyzer/found#redirects) describe a technique for doing custom redirection.

Here is a code sample of what I'm attempting to accomplish:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { viewer, children } = this.props;

    if (viewer === null && this.props.location.pathname != "/login") {
      throw new RedirectException({ action: "PUSH", pathname: "/login" });
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Basically I just want to redirect to the login page if there is no user. When I do this, the address bar correctly updates to `/login`, but I see an error in the console -

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?d2b3:744)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (ReactCompositeComponent.js?d2b3:723)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?d2b3:644)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.receiveComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?d2b3:546)
    at Object.receiveComponent (ReactReconciler.js?399b:124)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?d2b3:753)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (ReactCompositeComponent.js?d2b3:723)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?d2b3:644)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.receiveComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?d2b3:546)
    at Object.receiveComponent (ReactReconciler.js?399b:124)
```

If I do a page refresh at this point, the login page works just fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you want to redirect the user (and you don't care about the state of the application/components inside) you can just use `window.location = '/login'`

Comment: Cool, yea I'll consider that as a sort of fallback plan, but I'd also like to understand the more idiomatic approach to this

Comment: Do you know where exactly this exception was raised? Might be some external component that is not even relevant to your code...

Comment: That's another issue in and of itself. Updated the post to include the full stacktrace, which is decidedly unhelpful

Comment: while the rest of the world is using React Router...

Comment: @Hitmands the minute React Router [supports Relay modern](https://github.com/relay-tools/react-router-relay#react-router-relay--), I'm there 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to throw the `RedirectException` in the `render` method on the *route*, not on the route component.

Though if you're using Found Relay, for the time being you'd need to use `prerender` instead – see the example in https://github.com/4Catalyzer/found-relay/blob/v0.3.0-alpha.6/test/modern/prerender.test.js.

Comment: A follow-up - what technique would you recommend for redirection based on the results of a mutation, for example in the context of the `onCompleted` callback? It doesn't appear that `prerender` is being invoked in that case.